# Simple Tomcat cluster deployment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, nginx

I have a Tomcat 7 web app that I need to deploy to a dev server and then a small cluster. I maintain it in Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 64.

The dev server is a standalone Linux VM with Nginx and Tomcat 7.

The cluster is a pair of Linux VMs fronted by an Nginx load balancing proxy on another Linux VM. The Nginx server also has a Tomcat instance I use as a last staging step. i.e. I only run it for a test.

The Nginx server serves all static assets and proxies the rest to the Tomcat servers (*.do, *.jsp, etc)

So... All the servers have an identical directory structure directory with /var/webapps/app (tomcat), and /var/www/app (nginx). Nginx on the app servers allows me to test them in isolation.

It's a lot of work. I am still taking each node offline, updating the files manually, and bringing it back up after testing.

Is there an easier way? I don't want to just drop a war file on them as some of the files are different per server - e.g. web.xml is not identical.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/) is a deployment tool built with exactly your use case in mind. You can manage the differences in web.xml through configuration, deploy to the proxy using file server as part of the release and deploy to your small Tomcat cluster without downtime through rolling restarts. It's free for two servers.